# Java GUI Layout managers

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, grid-layout

It seems that I can do everything with a single Grid Layout--even tasks that might require multiple nested layouts if I did not use Grid Layout.  Is a single Grid Layout a better approach than many different nested layouts?

Comment: The later with gridlayout FTW

Comment: @mre first of all do not swear. I am just a school student and 13 so dont expect me to write the code to tingle your m**s v****a here. Learn to be polite. Do you ever wonder why people like you never have a social/s** life...Behave.

Comment: @mre maybe if you weren't so ****ing ******** ****, then you probablly have better things to do than undermining people. You got a small ****, is that why you do this? Higher stackoverflow ratings wont get you ********, you ****i*g *i*** of m*****b*****.

Comment: @user658911, Work on your grammar; that's all I'm asking for...a concise and coherent question. Thanks for the laugh. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most screens work very naturally with BorderLayout and it gives good resizing behavior to components inside it.

Personally I'd really rather nest various components inside a BorderLayout--possibly using Grid inside and possibly using others.

Experiment a lot with resizing behavior and see what you think.

Resizing is the key.